# How do I save a complex C# object in the database using ADO.NET and stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a complex C# object which needs to be persisted in multiple tables (around 12) in the database:

```
class Foo
{
    public Guid FooId { get; set; }
    public Bar[] Bars { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public Guid BarId { get; set; }
    public Guid FooId { get; set; }
    public Baz[] Bazs { get; set; }
}

class Baz
{
    public Guid BazId { get; set; }
    public Guid BarId { get; set; }
    // And so on ...
}
```

Questions:

1. What is the best way to send this complex object (an instance of `Foo`) as input to the stored procedure?
2. In the stored procedure how can I relate the corresponding `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` tables with its parent Ids (ex. `Bar` needs its parent `FooId`)?

Comment: What does the your stored procedure look like?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you appear to be modeling a standard relational database - each object could have its own save/restore method. My only suggestion would be in the child objects to store a reference to, for example, `Foo` instead of the `FooId`. This way you can go "up the ladder" from within the child classes. This way you could get to `FooId` by going: `Baz.Bar.Foo.FooId`

Comment: @Saruman I have not created the procedure yet. But I am thinking I can convert this object into datatables and pass it as table type parameters to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rough outline of how you might want to consider modeling it. This isn't by any means a complete skeleton (as you may want to play with the scope a bit), but should give a general idea. I've used models similar to this in several projects.

It may be possible to abstract these classes if they all follow the same type of data model.

```
class Foo
{
    public Guid FooId { get; private set; } // Only allow the object to define its Id.
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; } // Use a dynamic storage object.
    private bool Deleted { get; set; } // Monitors if the object has been deleted in the DB.

    public Foo()
    {
        this.FooId = Guid.Empty;
        this.Deleted = false;
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }

    public Foo(Guid fooId)
    {
        this.Deleted = false;

        this.FooId = fooId;
        LoadFromDatabase();

        Bars = new List<Bar>();
        LoadBarsFromDatabase();
    }

    private void LoadFromDatabase()
    {
        // Read from DB, set local variables...
    }

    private void LoadBarsFromDatabase()
    {
        // Psuedocode to load all Bars.
        foreach (var barData in barIdsLinkedToFooTable.Rows)
        {
            Bars.Add(new Bar(this, barData["barId"]));
        }
    }

    public void SaveToDatabase()
    {
        // If FooId is Guid.Empty, the record is new.
        // You may also want to consider the Deleted property value.
        // Either generate the new Guid first or let SQL do it for you in your SP.

        // Save Foo to DB with stored proc.

        // Save Bars.
        foreach (var bar in Bars)
        {
            bar.SaveToDatabase();
        }
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        // Delete via a stored proc.
        // Might be a good idea to set SQL to cascade the delete,
        //  this way all the children will be deleted automatically.

        this.Deleted = true;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public Guid BarId { get; private set; } // Only allow the local object to generate Id.
    public Foo ParentFoo { get; set; } // Store a reference to the parent.
    public List<Baz> Bazs { get; set; } // Use a dynamic storage object.
    private bool Deleted { get; set; } // Monitors if the object has been deleted in the DB.

    public Bar(Foo parentFoo)
    {
        // New Bar object.
        this.BarId = Guid.Empty;
        this.ParentFoo = parentFoo;
        this.Bazs = new List<Baz>();
        this.Deleted = false;
    }

    public Bar(Foo parentFoo, Guid barId)
    {
        // Create from existing object.
        this.Deleted = false;

        this.BarId = barId;
        this.ParentFoo = parentFoo;
        LoadFromDatabase();

        Bazs = new List<Baz>();
        LoadBazsFromDatabase();
    }

    /* DB methods for load, save, and delete similar to above. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should serialize your complex object into XML and pass it as parameter to stored procedure.

In stored procedure code you can query this XML. [TSQL Parse XML in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671772/tsql-parse-xml-in-stored-procedure)

In result you can reach high performance, but this way may become too difficult to maintain because stored procedure must know how to proceed your complex object.